# Android-UI: No focus marker when using hardware keyboard/barcode scanner

Tags: android, focus

At the moment I'm developing an app which uses a barcode reader to scan barcodes. The barcode reader is recognized as hardware keyboard by android. That works fine and I can read the barcodes. But when I read a barcode the Hamburger in the AppBar gets focused (see screenshot).
How can I get rid of that focus marker? I tried to set the focus to an other control but that doesn't work. Is it possible to override the style of the focus marker?

Screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/7zmzzhstx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working on that problem again I found a solution which works fine for me. Maybe that can help somebody else:

In my activity I override the public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) method to handle the input from the barcode scanner. I added now the following line of code:

```
containerContent.requestFocus();
```

The containerContent control is just a FrameLayout where are my fragments are hosted. I tried that already before I posted this question. But it didn't work because the FrameLayout is "not allowed" to request for focus. Now I modified also my layout xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</FrameLayout>
```

Added the `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` and now it works!